# SQL conversion table and count

Tags: sql, pivot

if I have table1 like this,

| Name | Test1 | Test2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 001 | 001 |
| Mary | 001 | 002.2 |
| Mike | 002.2 | 001 |
| Amy | 003 | 003 |

I want to bind with table2, like below, and conut.

| code | String |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | ADA |
| 002 | BAD |
| 002.2 | BAA |
| 003 | CTG |

I want to get this like that

| Name | Tom | Mary | Mike | Amy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADA | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| BAD | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| BAA | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| CTG | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

How can I achieve in SQL, Thank you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What's expected to happen if someone later adds the row (Bob, 001, 002) to table1? Do you suddenly want a Bob column too in the result?

Comment: RDBMS-MySQL, I  need to regular update ,too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the row-wise `name` values into column names in the output calls for a pivot technique, as explained in the first answer.

In order to `count` codes by name, you will also need a device to multiply rows based on code : two rows with `001` for name `Tom`, one row with `001` and one with `002.2` for name `Mary`, etc. Like so :

```
+----+-----+
|name|code |
+----+-----+
|Tom |001  |
|Tom |001  |
|Mary|001  |
|Mary|002.2|
|Mike|002.2|
|Mike|001  |
|Amy |003  |
|Amy |003  |
+----+-----+
```

which is easy to `count(*) ... group by (name, code)`, yielding a pivotable result.

How to achieve this may vary depending on your rdbms, here's my take in postgresql :

```sql
select table1.name, name_code.code, table2.string
from table1
-- create a row for each of (test2, test 2) of each row
cross join unnest(array[test1, test2]) name_code(code)
join table2 on name_code.code = table2.code
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6f4db79e502c59780bd03482d464f8ec) (without pivot)

Comment: Nice answer, but which dbms supports it?

Comment: @jarlh This is PostGreSQL >=10 (maybe backward-compatible), I admit I don't know how that works out in other dbms